# Deploying to Apple Business Manager customers

Tags: ios, app-store, publishing

I have a question with regards to the model of publishing to Apple Business Manager (ABM) customers which was covered in part in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816910/publishing-on-apple-business-manager).

To sum up, I can publish an app to ABM customers providing I have a list of their Apple IDs.

My question is if I need to know *all* of their Apple IDs at publish time, or if this list of Apple IDs can be amended in the future without recert?

I'd like to publish to one business customer's Apple ID, gain a customer, and add that new customer to the list so the new customer gets the app too.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an AppleID in the B2B section of App Store Connect at any time.

Once you have added the ID, they will be able to make volume purchases of your app through Apple Business Manager.

You do not need to change or rebuild the app.